# system.security.cryptography.SHA256Managed in .NET 4.5 (Windows 10)

Tags: .net, vba, sha256

I am using the following VBA function to get the SHA256 value for a file;

```
Public Function FileToSHA256(sfilename As String) As String
    Dim enc
    Dim bytes
    Dim outstr As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed")
    'Convert the string to a byte array and hash it
    bytes = GetFileBytes(sfilename)
    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((bytes))
    'Convert the byte array to a hex string
    For pos = 1 To LenB(bytes)
        outstr = outstr & LCase(Right("0" & Hex(AscB(MidB(bytes, pos, 1))), 2))
    Next
    FileToSHA256 = outstr 'Returns a 40 byte/character hex string
    Set enc = Nothing
End Function

Private Function GetFileBytes(ByVal path As String) As Byte()
    Dim lngFileNum As Long
    Dim bytRtnVal() As Byte
    lngFileNum = FreeFile
    If LenB(Dir(path)) Then ''// Does file exist?
        Open path For Binary Access Read As lngFileNum
        ReDim bytRtnVal(LOF(lngFileNum) - 1&) As Byte
        Get lngFileNum, , bytRtnVal
        Close lngFileNum
    Else
        Err.Raise 53
    End If
    GetFileBytes = bytRtnVal
    Erase bytRtnVal
End Function
```

This works perfectly under a Windows 7 environment on Word 2013. I do not know the .NET version this runs on (presuming 3.5).

It has now been launched onto a Windows 10 Environment (still Word 2013). I have been told by our IT dept that this is on .NET 4.5, but according to VBA its running from .NET frameworks 4.0.30319.

It now throws error  -

> Run-Time Error '-2146232576 (80131700)' Automation Error

on this line;

```
Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed")
```

I have MSCORLIB.DLL referenced in the project.

I can't figure out if I need to add additional references or change the code.

If a code change is necessary, it would need to cover the earlier version of .NET also, something with a case check to cover different versions, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but did you try adding the mscorlib from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`?

Comment: That didn't work I'm afraid. It may be because its in a corporate environment so I am a little locked down as to what access I have. I have managed to sort the issue by circumventing the mscorlib all together.

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to get mscorlib to work. But I found a module which circumvents it all together. It may be of use to others who have limited/no access to the full .NET framework.

http://khoiriyyah.blogspot.com/2012/06/vb6-hash-class-md5-sha-1-sha-256-sha.html

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with Windows 10 and .NET Framework 4.8. The solution was to add .NET Framework 3.5 from Windows Features ([image of the Windows Features dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9L7Y.png)). No changes in the code was needed.

Microsoft's .NET Framework 3.5 installation instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10